# How to use else statement

Tags: java

I tried in my code to use else statement, but I always get an error.

Here is my code, I wanna to say else `mode=0`.

```
public static int mode(int n[])
  {
      sort(n);
      int l[]=new int[n[n.length-1]+1];
      int mode = 0;
      int j = 0; // to count the number which repeated most
      int i=0;

      for ( i=0; i < n.length; i++) // for loop to go over all elements
      {
        l[n[i]]++; // increment the number
        if (j < l[n[i]]) 
            j = l[n[i]];
            mode = n[i];
        else
            mode=0;          
      }
      return mode;
  }
```

Comment: Remember: `java` is to `javascript` as `car` is to `carpet`

Comment: Can you print the n[] values ?

Answer (score 4):

Put braces in your if statement:

```
if (j < l[n[i]]){ 
    j = l[n[i]];
    mode = n[i];
}
```

Without braces, `mode = n[i];` will always be executed

Comment: I tried that , but I always get 0 , even if the condition is true

Comment: yes. because when `j < l[n[i]]` is `false` you set `mode` to `0`. the method is incorrect anymore

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, try this.

```
public static int mode(int n[])
  {

  sort(n);
  int l[]=new int[n[n.length-1]+1];
  int mode = 0;
  int j = 0; // to count the number which repeated most
  int i=0;



for ( i=0; i < n.length; i++) // for loop to go over all elements
 {
    l[n[i]]++; // increment the number
    if (j < l[n[i]]){ 
        j = l[n[i]];
        mode = n[i];}
    else
        mode=0;






}
return mode;


  }
```

The reason you were getting an error for your else statement when you compiled is that an else expects an "if" clause directly before it.  However, by not putting brackets around the if statement the compiler was always executing the line "mode = n[i];" since it was not technically included in the if statement.

Basically, the solution was to add brackets for your if statement.  When you wish to add more than one line of code to an if statement, while/for loop or else statement, you need brackets.  It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: thanks, but I still get 0 even if the condition is true

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int mode(int n[])
{
    sort(n);
    int l[]=new int[n[n.length-1]+1];
    int mode = 0;
    int j = 0; // to count the number which repeated most
    int i=0;

    for ( i=0; i < n.length; i++) // for loop to go over all elements
    {
        l[n[i]]++; // increment the number
        if (j < l[n[i]]) 
        { // After this bracket if true
            j = l[n[i]];
            mode = n[i];
        } // to here
        else
        { // This is where your else code happens
            mode=0;
        } // to here
    }
    return mode;
}
```

If I remember correctly, if you don't have the {}s after an if, only the first line happens. [Don't hold me to this.]  The {}s are always a good idea to use.

Any time you have an if, include the {}s, even if it's only 1 line for clarity and to simplify future editing.